# Trying to use script tag for video player, page source isn't showing the code loaded

Tags: javascript

This is really strange and I've never encountered it before. I have a javascript script tag that I'm using on one of my xenforo pages, but it's not showing up so I commented it out for testing. Here's what's weird:

When I comment the code, view page source shows the code as commented, but when I go to uncomment it again then page source shows no trace of it and it's just removed.

Has anyone ever experienced this? This is the only javascript tag I can see that's doing this, but I can add anything else in its place and it shows properly, but given the fact that it shows when commented I just can't seem to figure out what's going on.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

UPDATE: adding code

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('test function')
    </script>
  
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
console.log('in function now');
        var site_id = 0000;
        var data_site_id = 0;

        var sn_cb = new Date().getMonth();
        var snack_hb = document.createElement('script');
        snack_hb.src = 'https://cdn-header-bidding.snack-media.com/assets/js/snack-loader/'+site_id+'?cb='+sn_cb;
        snack_hb.id = 'snack_ads';
        if(data_site_id){
            snack_hb.setAttribute('data-site-id',data_site_id);
        }
        console.log(snack_hb);
        document.body.appendChild(snack_hb);
        snack_hb.onerror = function(){
            document.body.removeChild(snack_hb);
            var snack_hb2 = document.createElement('script');
            snack_hb2.src = 'https://cdn2-header-bidding.snack-media.com/assets/js/snack-loader/'+site_id+'?cb='+sn_cb;
            snack_hb2.id = 'snack_ads';
            if(data_site_id){
                snack_hb2.setAttribute('data-site-id',data_site_id);
            }
            document.body.appendChild(snack_hb2);
        };
    })();
</script>
</head>
```

If I run this, then I see the 'test function' print in console, but the script below it literally doesn't exist on the page

Comment: Show us the code so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @Grumpy my bad, I added the code now. It's showing the test function in the console but no trace of the block below it (on phone and incognito on desktop as well)

Comment: Running your code snippet shows the `<script>` and `in fucntion now` print to the console.  I can also see the script is appended to the body in the dev tools. Are you sure this is the exact code that is in your project?

Comment: @PsiKai this is all I have on the page right now (except for empty body opening and closing tags) but absolutely no content. It feels like comething on the site is blocking it once the url is created (everything up to it shows in the inspector if I run it in sections but once the url portion hits it's like it renders it nonexistent)

Comment: When i open the link in a browser, there is no data, response 200 but zero data.